# error: class SplashScreen is public, should be declared in a file named SplashScreen.java public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to write a program, but I'm getting this compiler error:

**error: class SplashScreen is public, should be declared in a file named SplashScreen.java
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {**

here is my code :

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvSplash;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `SplashScree` in the same java file with `AppCompatActivity` called `AppCompatActivity.java`,then you need to remove `public` for `SplashScree` to make sure they can in the same java file

```
class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {// in the same java file
```

Otherwise,you need to create a new java file called `SplashScreen.java`(would be better in the same package) if you still want to keep `public` key word

```
 public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {// in separate java file
```